Coolant reduces but engine not overheating
I've noticed a strange issue on my 2003 Mitsubishi Montero Sport (6g72 3.0l engine). The coolant reduces from the coolant reservoir a bit after a drive and the amount is not consistent. I mostly notice it after a short drive. There are not visible leaks, engine doesn't overheat, engine oil looks fine, there is no smoke from the tail pipe and the compression tests were ok (did not indicate any compression leaks for the age).
Any idea what maybe causing this? I noticed this mostly after a coolant change done by the service station. Can this occur if the system wasn't bled properly?
Thanks

Do you ever need to add coolant? Or does the level go down during/after the drive, then go back to normal when the vehicle is cooled down?

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Need to add coolant in the morning to the reservoir. the radiator is filled to the brim

Have you done (or had done) for a head gasket leak from the radiator? If there is a small head gasket leak where coolant is going into a cylinder, it could be small enough to not show at the tail pipe, yet routinely lose coolant.

Original water pump may be worn. Some pumps have a bottom weep hole, allowing coolant to leak when the bearing is worn. Loosen or remove the drive belt and manually  rock the pump pully.

Thanks alot @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 and @F Dryer.  Will give those a check!

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I did the gasket leak test through the radiator as well..no indication of a gasket leak. This coolant reduction mostly noted in short drives. I drove 300+km and back and noticed hardly any coolant lost, only on short drives which has more stop n go's I notice the reduction

@FDryer there seems to be no physical indication or any coolant leaks near the area. As I mentioned above, in the last long drive I did 300km+ I noticed hardly/ no coolant reduction. Its on the short drives 10-20km stop n go instances I notice the reduction

Perform a coolant pressure test if you can, borrowing a cooling system pressure test kit from Autozone or other auto store providing free tool loans. Hot coolant leaking out will evaporate in a hot engine environment, leaving traces of residue almost indistinguishable from every vehicle collecting whatever is drawn in thru the front grille.

@FDryer thank you.. will try that as well..

@FDryer Did the tests, I suspect its the overflow tank lid. It comes in 2 pieces..the center part holds the overflow tube and the surrounding part threads it to the tank. I noticed some residue on the top of it thinking that when I go over rough roads its spilling over the top. planning to have some sort of solution to better seal the 2 surfaces and try if it helps.

@FDryer radiator cap fan all are fine. No overheating.. no external internal leaks. just the coolant reduces from the overflow tank. Thats y we checked the tank

Tested the radiator cap or was it replaced? Older vehicles use a fan clutch that engages as cooling system temperatures rise. If it's worn out, it may spin easily by hand. If the f/c  spins easily by hand, it won't draw in cooling air thru the radiator. Resistance to spinning would suggest a good fan clutch. Some replace it with electric fans to cure overheating problems
